# What is causing this to look for another picture?

Tags: html, css

I'm making a website for a restaurant and ran into a problem. I wanted to use some sexy code and have the picture pop up when you're hovering your mouse above it. Everything's fine except that I always get the little file not found thing underneath the 'preview' image.

My question is: What is it trying to look for? What is it looking for?

Here's the HTML and CSS:

```css
ul.enlarge{
list-style-type:none; /*remove the bullet point*/
margin-left:0;
}
ul.enlarge li{
display:inline-block; /*places the images in a line*/
position: relative;
z-index: 0; /*resets the stack order of the list items - later we'll increase this*/
margin:10px 40px 0 20px;
}
ul.enlarge img{
background-color:#eae9d4;
padding: 6px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(132, 132, 132, .75);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(132, 132, 132, .75);
box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(132, 132, 132, .75);
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
border-radius: 4px;
}
ul.enlarge span{
position:absolute;
left: -9999px;
background-color:#eae9d4;
padding: 10px;
font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
font-size:.9em;
text-align: center;
color: #495a62;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0, .75));
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0, .75);
box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0, .75);
-webkit-border-radius: 8px;
-moz-border-radius: 8px;
border-radius:8px;
}
ul.enlarge li:hover{
z-index: 50;
cursor:pointer;
}
ul.enlarge span img{
padding:2px;
background:#ccc;
}
ul.enlarge li:hover span{
top: -300px; /*the distance from the bottom of the thumbnail to the top of the popup image*/
left: -20px; /*distance from the left of the thumbnail to the left of the popup image*/
}
ul.enlarge li:hover:nth-child(2) span{
left: -100px;
}
ul.enlarge li:hover:nth-child(3) span{
left: -200px;
}
/**IE Hacks - see http://css3pie.com/ for more info on how to use CS3Pie and to download the latest version**/
ul.enlarge img, ul.enlarge span{
behavior: url(pie/PIE.htc);
}
```

```html
<div class="container specials clearfix">

  <section id="column-specials">

    <div id="lead-in">
      <h3>Unsere laufenden Angebote:</h3>
    </div>
    <!-- end lead-in -->


    <ul class="enlarge">
      <li>
        <img src="images/buffet4.jpg" alt="Unser reichlich gedecktes Buffet" />
        <span>
                                                                        <img src="images/buffet5.jpg" alt="Unser reichlich gedecktes Buffet" />
                                                                                <br />Unser reichlich gedecktes Buffet</span>
      </li>

      <li>
        <img src="images/gyros_prev2.jpg" alt="Unser leckeres Gyros Pita" />
        <span>
                                                                        <img src="images/gyros_prev.jpg" alt="Unser leckeres Gyros Pita" />
                                                                                <br />Unser frisch zubereitetes Gyros Pita</span>
      </li>
    </ul>


    <!-- test -->
    <div class="columnbuffet">
      <h4>Unser Buffet</h4>
      <p>Unser Buffet findet jeden X und Y statt. Nur 9,90 &euro; pro Person.</p>
      <img src="images/b.uffet3.jpg" alt="Unser reichlich gedecktes Buffet">
    </div>
    <!-- end columnbuffet -->

    <div class="columngyros">
      <h4>Das Gyros Pita Spezial</h4>
      <p>Beim Kauf von 2 Gyros Pita erhalten Sie ein drittes Umsonst.</p>
      <img src="images/g.yros_prev.jpg" alt="Unser leckeres Gyros Pita">
    </div>
    <!-- end columngyros -->
    <!-- end test -->

  </section>

</div>
<!-- end specials -->
```

Also a link to [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/3R0XYYzX).

I did copy the code from http://cssdemos.tupence.co.uk/image-popup.htm and I checked it but I can't seem to find the error.

Comment: I had to use pastebin due to not being able to post the code here.

Comment: Use [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) here I made one for you: [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/o9LqcLfe/)

Comment: This doesn't help me. My problem is that I don't just get the picture as a preview and when you hover your mouse over it it expands but that I get a second thing what's displaying that some file is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your site is at `http://www.example.com`, and that there's a directory on your server which can be accessed at `http://www.example.com/images`, you should just be able to add a `/` (forward slash) in front of all the `<img src="` values, like so:

Change this:

```
<img src="images/gyros_prev2.jpg" alt="Unser leckeres Gyros Pita" />
```

To this:

```
<img src="/images/gyros_prev2.jpg" alt="Unser leckeres Gyros Pita" />
```

That's certainly not a guaranteed fix since it's kind of hard to determine the root of the problem, but a good portion of the time it's a small detail which gets overlooked and causes big problems.

Comment: Well, that just made all the images disappear to this: http://i.imgur.com/4PgePMy.png from this: http://i.imgur.com/SFjpRJi.png (left without changing to your suggestion)
I write on my computer and have everything in a folder, the index.html in the root folder then comes the images and styles folder.